# Batch Script File Transfer with Variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Thank you for taking your time to help me with the problem I'm trying to solve. I have written some of the batch file but I don't have much experience so this a bit difficult for me. I'm trying to transfer pdf files from a specific location to individual folders in another location. Each file will contain this format 
"GOOGLE EARTH_2018-08-07_5485A635.pdf" and based on "GOOGLE EARTH_" it will transfer it to it's rightful folder named as such "GOOGLE EARTH_Google Corporation". So based on the initial part of the file, transfer it to folder that begins with specified file name. This is what I have so far but doesn't work.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Alpha\Documents\NOTEPAD Coding\File Transfer Coding\Files"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Alpha\Documents\NOTEPAD Coding\File Transfer Coding\Transfer"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.pdf" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=_-" %%b IN ("%%a") ) DO (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*%%b*" '
  ) DO (
   MOVE "%%a" "%sourcedir%\%%d\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Not really understanding what you are doing with all of those nested `FOR` commands but you are missing a closing parentheses.  If you are trying to transfer `PDF` files why are you iterating `XML` files with the first `FOR` command?

Comment: @Squashman I put that code together from very little knowledge, still trying to understand all the pieces. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I gave you two, that I guess you didn't understand so I guess I will spell it out. The `IN` clause of the first `FOR` command is running the `DIR` command which is looking for `XML` files.  You said you wanted to look for `PDF` files.  You have three `FOR` command blocks.  Which means you have three opening left parentheses.  Every opening parentheses needs a closing right parentheses.

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the formatting of the code for readability.  If you use this syntax it makes it very easy to see when you are missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: You need to use your `sourcedir` variable with the `MOVE` command.

Comment: @Squashman thank you for your help, I made the changes you suggested but still no luck.

Comment: Update your question with any additional code changes you have made. We can only give you guidance based on the information you have provided. With the information you provided I cannot make any other suggestions.

Comment: @Squashman updated with the changes made

Comment: You made 1 of three changes.  I formatted your code so that you could CLEARLY see where the missing parentheses was.  Each `FOR` was aligned with a closing parentheses.  What logic were you using to put a closing after a closing parentheses before the `DO`????  I also said you needed to use the `SOURCEDIR` with the `MOVE` command. I didn't say to remove the destination directory from the MOVE command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my answer I have aligned your code for extreme readability to show you how the closing parentheses lines up with each `FOR` command.  I changed the `MOVE` command to use the source directory variable because the first `FOR` variable only holds the file name.  Also changed the first `IN` clause to iterate `PDF` files.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Alpha\Documents\NOTEPAD Coding\File Transfer Coding\Files"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Alpha\Documents\NOTEPAD Coding\File Transfer Coding\Transfer"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.pdf" ') DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=_-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
        FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*%%b*" ') DO (
            MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\"
        )
    )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you I appreciate it! I will study the code closer and test a bit further. Thank you very much!!