# Move files into a subfolder of a destination directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I started using batch commands last week and I've reached a real obstacle with a script I made.

**What I want to do**

Move a PDF file from `C:\Users\JK\Documents\reports PDFs` into pre-made subfolders in the destination `W:\Departments\QA\cases`.

For example the script would move `2223 report.pdf` to `W:\Departments\QA\cases\2201 - 2300\2223`

**What I tried**

I made a script based off the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286297)

```
cls
@pushd %~dp0

@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\Users\JK\Documents\reports PDFs"
set "DestDir=W:\Departments\QA\cases\"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\*.pdf" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "eol=| tokens=1" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        for /D %%C in ("%DestDir%\%%B*") do move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%%C\"
    )
)

endlocal
popd

pause
```

**Where I am stuck**

How could I add subfolders or account for them in the destination directory?

FYI, I also tried adding a wildcard symbol at the end of the destination directory by changing `%DestDir%\%%B` to `%DestDir%\*\%%B*`.

Comment: So you have the number of the file which corresponds to the directory that is TWO levels deep but you need to get the directory that specifies the range.  You have two simple options. 1) Figure out the range directory based on the numbers in the name of the file. You could do some simple IF comparisons to do that or some basic math.  2) Use a `FOR /D /R` to find the final sub-directory.  The `/D /R` combined together will walk the directory tree and find the directory path you are looking for

Comment: Thanks @Squashman I tried your 2nd suggestion no luck unfortunately i just added /R so line reads for /D /R %%C.                                                                    
 I also tried 2 other suggestions but no luck:                       
1) for /D /S %%C  2) for /D /b /o:n /a:d

Comment: You only explained how you tried one of my options. Your "two" other suggestions are not valid.  There is not `/S` option with the `FOR` command, nor are there `/b /o:n /a:d` options for the `FOR` command.

Comment: Ok no worries, thanks for taking the time to help me @Squashman I appreciate your experience. Do you have any suggestions for making the /D /R %%C code work? Perhaps I need to adjust my code further?   here is the full line: for /D /R %%C in ("%DestDir%\%%B*") do move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%%C\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably accomplish the task with the following script (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=C:\Users\JK\Documents\reports PDFs" & rem // (source directory; `.` or `` is current, `%~dp0.` is script parent)
set "_TARGET=W:\Departments\QA\cases" & rem // (target directory; `.` or `` is current, `%~dp0.` is script parent)
set "_SUBDIR=#"      & rem // (set to non-blank value in order to create individual sub-directories)
set "_FMASK=????*.pdf"    & rem // (pattern to match source files)
set "_DMASK=???? - ????*" & rem // (pattern to match target directories)
set "_FFIL1=^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789] .*\.pdf$" & rem // (filter 1 for source files)
set "_FFIL2=^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\.pdf$"    & rem // (filter 2 for source files)
set "_DFIL1=^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789] - [0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789] .*$"
set "_DFIL2=^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789] - [0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]$"

rem // Change into source directory:
pushd "%_SOURCE%" && (
    rem // Iterate through all files matching the specified pattern and filters:
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
        dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%_FMASK%" ^| findstr /I /R /C:"%_FFIL1%" /C:"%_FFIL2%"
    ') do (
        rem // Store full path of currently iterated file:
        set "FILE=%%~fF"
        rem // Extract the leading numeric part of the file name:
        for /F "eol=| delims= " %%N in ("%%~nF") do (
            rem // Store the numeric part:
            set "NUM=%%N"
            rem /* Remove any leading zeros from the numeric part of the file name, because
            rem    such cause the number to be unintentionally interpreted as octal: */
            set /A "INT=0" & for /F "eol=| tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%%N") do 2> nul set /A "INT=%%Z"
        )
        rem // Change into target directory:
        pushd "%_TARGET%" && (
            rem // Iterate through all directories matching the specified pattern and filters:
            for /F "eol=| delims=" %%D in ('
                cmd /V /C 2^> nul dir /B /A:D-H-S "!_DMASK:|=%%I!" ^| findstr /I /R /C:"%_DFIL1%" /C:"%_DFIL2%"
            ') do (
                rem // Store name of currently iterated directory:
                set "TDIR=%%D"
                rem // Extract first (from) and second (to) numeric parts of directory names:
                for /F "eol=| tokens=1-2 delims=- " %%S in ("%%D") do (
                    rem // Remove any leading zeros from first (from) numeric part:
                    set /A "FRM=0" & for /F "eol=| tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%%S") do set /A "FRM=%%Z"
                    rem // Remove any leading zeros from second (to) numeric part:
                    set /A "TOO=0" & for /F "eol=| tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%%T") do set /A "TOO=%%Z"
                )
                rem // Toggle delayed variable expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem /* Do integer comparisons to check whether the numeric part of the file name
                rem    lies within the range given by the directory name (from/to): */
                if !INT! geq !FRM! if !INT! leq !TOO! (
                    rem // Numeric part of file name lies within range, hence try to move file:
                    if defined _SUBDIR (
                        2> nul md "!TDIR!\!NUM!"
                        ECHO move "!FILE!" "!TDIR!\!NUM!\"
                    ) else (
                        ECHO move "!FILE!" "!TDIR!\"
                    )
                )
                endlocal
            )
            rem // Return from target directory:
            popd
        )
    )
    rem // Return from source directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

You may need to adapt a few constants to your situation in the section commented with `Define constants here:` at the top.

After having tested the script for the correct output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands** in front of the `move` commands! In order to avoid multiple `1 file(s) moved.` messages, replace these `ECHO` commands by `> nul`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @aschipfl really appreciate this. I checked the constants and confirmed/set them to my target & source directory. Unfortunately nothing happened. The black cmd screen popped up but didnt show any errors/info just the flashing dash -                 
                                                                                                                               
1) I noticed in the script the FFIL pattern is different to the DFIL e.g.  FFIL1 is *\ whereas DFIL is *$. Can this have an effect?

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run the script by navigating to the script's parent path (using [`cd /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)) and then typing the script's name. You've read the bold text in the answer, haven't you?

Comment: Hi @aschipfl 1) I tried running the script from cmd also with ECHO replaced with > nul. Unfortunately it mentions UNC paths are not supported. 2) the source directory actually starts \\svr-vddv-fs01\Users rather than C:\Users I didn't want to mention it since its a work network drive. However I can see you have pushd and popd in the script to deal with this kind of issue. Stumped really. I might ask the software engineers at work or find a batch/cmd forum and post on there see what they suggest. Thanks though

Comment: Is the destination directory a UNC path too?

Comment: Its a shared network drive, it starts W:/Departments.  However if I try the script with the same destination directory  as the source but a different subfolder it still doesn't work. For example source directory C:\Users\JK\Documents\reports PDFs and destination C:\Users\JK\Documents\scans. No worries though I'll ask at work or on the batch forums. Thanks

Comment: Strange... What values did you set the constants to?

Comment: I changed two of the constants 1) source and 2) target to include the full file path e.g.  C:\Users\JK became \\svr-vddv-fs01\Users\JK. The rest of the constants e.g. SUBDIR, FFIL, FMASK, DFIL I left untouched.

Comment: Well, the script should be able to handle UNC paths for both source and target (I tested it meanwhile). Is it possible that you forgot to specify the correct sub-directories? for instance, the target directory should point to the one that contains the `2201 - 2300` directories, and the source should point to the one that directly contains the files to be processed. Are the file names really consisting of a four-digit number plus a space pluse something else? are the target sub-directories really containing two four-digit numbers with space + hyphen plus space in between?

Comment: Oh my goodness that was the issue all along. The filenames are the wrong syntax. In my quest to make the subdirectory as "anonymous" as possible before posting here I forgot to include the leading COMP-. The real subdirectory reads as ...QA\cases\COMP-2201 - 2300\ rather than QA\cases\2201 - 2300\ as I posted in my question above. Removing the COMP- it worked perfectly, thank you. Sorry about how long it took I've learnt an important lesson about syntax when posting.

Comment: I guess in future if i do have leading characters in front of a numeric part of the file name I can adapt the delim part of your script. For example to ignore COMP- I could have done:  rem // Remove any leading COMP- :
                    set /A "FRM=0" & for /F "eol=| tokens=* delims=COMP-" %%Z in ("%%S") do set /A "FRM=%%Z". Thanks so much @aschipfl for your answer really learnt a lot from this.

Comment: You're welcome! When the target directory names are preceded with `COMP-` or something similar, you could change `tokens=1-2` to `tokens=2-3` in line # 40, then change `set "_DMASK=???? - ????*"` to `set "_DMASK=*-???? - ????*"` in line # 9, and finally, in lines # 12 and 13, insert `[^-][^-]*--*` behind the `^` character...

Comment: Perfect thanks, will keep this in mind for future!!